# Crashes when uploading files with special characters to OneDrive

Tags: 22.04

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. I am trying to upload some files and folders to OneDrive. The files have portuguese characteres, like `çãáàéê`, etc.

Every file or folder with special characters crashes without being able to be upload them to cloud.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Certain file systems can not handle special characters in filenames. It's generally recommended to avoid using special characters in filenames for this reason. Problems often arise when you try to move files from one file system to a different file system with different rules and specifications.

Comment: @guiverc Let's assume Ubuntu 22.04, since it was tagged this way. Ubuntu Core is a niche product for most people anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

> Every file or folder with special characters crashes without being able to be upload them to cloud.

The application should not crash.

Please follow the correct support process as detailed here: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive#reporting-an-issue-or-bug